# Get list which has minimum value from nested list that has different types

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have list with different elements (string and float), an example:

```
X = [['carrier', 'arrivaldelay', 'MAX', 0.43085409548228853],
 ['carrier', 'weatherdelay', 'SUM', 0.45040808607625615],
 ['carrier', 'arrivaldelay', 'SUM', 0.4166832477676661],
 ['destination', 'departurdelay', 'MAX', 0.4009409407356311],
 ['destination', 'arrivaldelay', 'AVG', 0.4216147060142493],
 ['origin', 'arrivaldelay', 'AVG', 0.4353396150129142],
 ['origin', 'arrivaldelay', 'MIN', 0.4157363968474399],
 ['origin', 'arrivaldelay', 'STD', 0.4478847651966835]]
```

What is the simple and efficient way to get the list which has minimum value based on the last value,

Expected output : `['destination', 'departurdelay', 'MAX', 0.4009409407356311]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most simple I can think of:

```
min(X, key=lambda x: x[-1])
```

Comment: And, without the `lambda` - `import operator; min(X, key=operator.itemgetter(-1))`